Get backtrace for timer error
For an error in a timer there is
Error running timer: (text-read-only "Attempt to change text outside editable field")

Sadly it does not give a hint which function in which buffer has the problem.
Is it possible to trigger a backtrace at this point? The variable debug-on-error is already t but does not seem to help in a timer.

M-x list-timers might give you some pointers.

See the Elisp manual, node Standard Errors.
The standard error in question here is text-read-only. That refers you to node Special Properties, which says this (in part) for read-only:

If a character has the property read-only, then modifying that character is not allowed. Any command that would do so gets an error, text-read-only. If the property value is a string, that string is used as the error message.

And in your case the error message is Attempt to change text outside editable field.

If debug-on-error doesn't give you the context/debugger (maybe errors during timers are excluded) then try wrapping your timer code that raises the error with condition-case, providing a handler for the error text-read-only - see node Handling Errors. You can try invoking the debugger in the handler code: (debug), or you can just call message to provide you with some context info.
